# WordPress url transformation script

Tags: database, migration, scripts

Does anyone know of or have suggestions for how to go about setting up a WordPress url transformation script - perhaps via a plugin or one-time run script?

It would be used to correct installs which are deployed between each other and across servers and would need to work on network installs with unlimited sub-sites.

An example would be:

- Install One

  - Main site: install-one-main.com
  - Sub site 2: install-one-sub-one.com
- Install Two

  - Main site: install-two-main.com
  - Sub site 2: install-two-sub-one.com

Network installs are [more complex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Multisite) to update domain references in the db as they are stored in several tables - including numeric tables ( i.e wp_2_options ) created on the fly.

I am not looking for someone to write this solution for me - just hints, tips, ideas and if possible a link to an existing repo that will serve as a starting point.

> Multisite is somewhat more complicated to move, as the database itself has multiple references to the server name as well as the folder locations. If you're simply moving to a new server with the same domain name, you can copy the files and database over, exactly as you would a traditional install.
>
> If, instead, you are changing domains, then the best way to move Multisite is to move the files, edit the .htaccess and wp-config.php (change DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE and, if the folder name containing Multisite changed, PATH_CURRENT_SITE), and then manually edit the database. Search for all instances of your domain name, and change them as needed. This step cannot yet be easily automated. It's safe to search/replace any of the wp_x_posts tables, however do not attempt blanket search/replace without the Search and Replace for WordPress Databases script (aka the interconnectit script).
>
> If you're moving Multisite from one folder to another, you will need to make sure you edit the wp_blogs entries to change the folder name correctly. You should manually review both wp_site and wp_blogs regardless, to ensure all sites were changed correctly.
>
> Also, manually review all the wp_x_options tables and look for three fields and edit them as needed:
>
> - home
> - siteurl
> - fileupload_url
>
> If you are moving from subdomains to subfolders, or vice-versa, remember to adjust the .htaccess file and the value for SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL in your wp-config.php file accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The pro version of "Duplicator" should be able to handle that. I remeber to have used that once for a situation similar to what you describe.

Comment: Problem is that our host - WPEngine - bans this system.